# What is the proper way to debug multi-module maven project with VSCode?

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Here's some background to my particular case. I was given a multi-module maven project and opened the entire project as one workspace in VSCode. The modules are deployed to a JBoss server as `.war` files. Each module has its own `artifactId` and can make calls to other modules (through HTTP or other protocols). I created a `launch.json` file in `.vscode` directory. This `.vscode` directory sits among other modules right under the project root. The `launch.json` file contains the following content:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "java",
      "name": "Debug (Attach) - Remote",
      "request": "attach",
      "hostName": "<ip_address>",
      "port": 8787
    }
  ]
}
```

This works if I don't need to evaluate statements in the debug console. I could also add `"projectName": "<artifactId>"` when I need to evaluate statements for a single module. However, **I could not debug multiple modules at one time**. What I'm currently doing is to 1) stop the debugger, 2) edit `projectName` to the next module's `artifactId`, 3) attach the debugger again (and fire a new request). **This doesn't sound like the optimal way of debugging this type of projects in VSCode.** Note that I also tried to put the parent POM `artifactId` or even the project root directory name as `projectName`, but they didn't work neither (in this case, it simply says "*Cannot evaluate because of java.lang.IllegalStateException: Project <name> cannot be found*").

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set **projectName** to a wildcard?

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
        "type": "java",
        "name": "Debug (Attach) - Remote",
        "request": "attach",
        "hostName": "<ip_address>",
        "projectName": "*",
        "port": 8787
      }
    ]
  }
```

As far as I remember, wildcard support is debugger-dependent, so this might not work if the Java debugger hasn't implemented it.

However, you may want to create multiple configurations to avoid having to replace the **projectName** every time:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
        "type": "java",
        "name": "Debug (Attach) - Remote - Prj1",
        "request": "attach",
        "hostName": "<ip_address>",
        "projectName": "project1",
        "port": 8787
      },
      {
        "type": "java",
        "name": "Debug (Attach) - Remote - Prj2",
        "request": "attach",
        "hostName": "<ip_address>",
        "projectName": "project2",
        "port": 8787
      }
    ]
  }
```

You'll be able to easly run the one you need from the **Run and Debug** dropdown menu.

Edit: Just noticed that the question is 3 years old... Oh well, if it's still needed